# Ubuntu randomly freezes when I press certain keys

Tags: boot, keyboard, hardware, freeze

This is a weird issue I'm facing recently. I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop *(Acer E 15 E5-571G-51XR)* and it was doing pretty fine until a weird issue popped up roughly 3 weeks later. Whenever I would press the key `T` on my laptop keyboard, the current screen would freeze - cannot move the cursor, keyboard stops working - followed by a black screen (the screen doesn't turn off; I can see the backlight). Only thing I'm able to do is a forced power off (pressing the power key for sometime until the system powers down). Also, this behaviour is completely random; it does not happen every time I press `T`. It is just random. Can anyone help me with this weird situation?

Some more information on this,

1. I got this issue on LiveCD too.
2. Ubuntu 14.04 has a similar tale.
3. I popped the `T` key, cleaned the membrane inside, kept it back. The issue persists.
4. There's nothing printed about the freeze in `dmesg` or `syslog`. In fact, there are absolutely no entries in any of the logs from the time when the system freezes till it starts again.
5. One interesting thing. When I turn on the laptop after the forced power down, it boots normally except on one screen where you actually see a terminal like view which prints the boot messages. On that screen, I can see a pattern being continuously printed as if someone has kept some key pressed. Something like this `^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@`. And only when I press some other key, the stream stops.
6. I got another USB keyboard and it didn't give me any issues so far. I guess it's related to the keyboard on the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue was with the hardware membrane for the `T` key. I popped out the key, tried pushing the membrane hard (Ubuntu froze and got a black screen), tried lifting the membrane up a little, cleaned it. Since then, I didn't get any issues so far. It seems, moving the membrane a little bit did the trick.